# Cinnamon: specific css style for each panel

Tags: debian, cinnamon, panel

In file `~/.themes/.../cinnamon.css` one can edit the style for all panels in cinnamon. But every panel will have the same style setting.

Now let's say (for example) I have 2 panels, one should have blue background, the other one red. Is there a way how to achieve this in cinnamon? I don't want the "click here and here" solution. Command line + config files only. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `.panel-top` and `.panel-bottom` settings instead of `#panel` which sets them globally.